# What is the difference of an Inkscape installation via MacPorts with +Quartz or +X11 option?

Tags: macos, macports, x11, xquartz

For macOS (High Sierra) `Inkscape` can be installed via `MacPorts` with two options: `+Quartz` or `+X11`. What is the difference? Which version is (more) recommended?

Comment: You can download a proper standalone Mac app version of Inkscape that doesn't need MacPorts.

Comment: @benwiggy: thx for the hint. I just installed V1.1.2 - I hope it is stable and is working as the previous V0.92.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is what windowing system and graphical layer the program that is being built to use.

X11 is the X Window System that is used on most Unix and Unix like systems (e.g. most Linux(there is now Wayland) and non Apple/NeXT)

Quartz is a slightly ill defined term that covers much of the graphics and display functions of macOS.

In general the Quartz option will provide a program that looks and feels more like other macOS programs whilst X11 will look and feel like how it would run on other Unix computers. The look and feel includes where menus are placed, mouse click behaviour, cut and paste.

In Macports you must choose one or the other for **all** your ports.

In my opinion use +Quartz unless you know exactly why you want to use +X11 (I think +quartz is the default)

Comment: Why does MacPorts default to X11? If you download Inkscape from their website, you get the Quartz/Aqua-version don't you?

Comment: @d-b You might be correct that x11 is not the default - on reading my last sentence I can read the default as being either - so I"ll edit that - I have used mac ports since 2002 and lost track of the default.